# bind_param(): variables != parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I've just been trying to get this working for about 2 hours now, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

This is the error I'm getting :

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /demo/records.php on line 117

also here:

```
    <?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/

// connect to the database
include("connect-db.php");

// creates the new/edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($emri = '', $cmimi ='', $error = '', $id = '')
{ ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?>
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?></h1>
<?php if ($error != '') {
echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
. "</div>";
} ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php if ($id != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<?php } ?>

<strong>vEmri: *</strong> <input type="text" name="vEmri"
value="<?php echo $emri; ?>"/><br/>
<strong>vCmimi: *</strong> <input type="text" name="vCmimi"
value="<?php echo $cmimi; ?>"/>
<p>* required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php }



/*

EDIT RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
// get variables from the URL/form
$id = $_POST['id'];
$vEmri = htmlentities($_POST['vEmri'], ENT_QUOTES);
$vCmimi= htmlentities($_POST['vCmimi'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($vEmri == '' || $vCmimi == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($vEmri, $vCmimi, $error, $id);
}
else
{
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE veturat SET vEmri = ?, vCmimi= ?
WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $vEmri, $vCmimi, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
// make sure the 'id' value is valid
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
// get 'id' from URL
$id = $_GET['id'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM veturat WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $vEmri, $vCmimi);
$stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($vEmri, $vCmimi, NULL, $id);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
else
{
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
}



/*

NEW RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get the form data
$vEmri= htmlentities($_POST['vEmri'], ENT_QUOTES);
$vCmimi = htmlentities($_POST['vCmimi'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($vEmri == '' || $vCmimi == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($vEmri, $vCmimi, $error);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT veturat (vEmri, vCmimi) VALUES (?, ?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $vEmri, $vCmimi);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirec the user
header("Location: view.php");
}

}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
renderForm();
}
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: The code should be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the columns fetched explicitly. This should work (line 112):

```
// get the record from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, vEmri, vCmimi, vNgjyra, vLenda, vTransmisioni, vKilometra, vProdhimi, vVellimi FROM veturat WHERE id=?"))
{
   $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
   $stmt->execute();

   $stmt->bind_result($id, $vEmri, $vCmimi, $vNgjyra, $vLenda, $vTransmisioni, $vKilometra, $vProdhimi, $vVellimi);
   $stmt->fetch();

   // show the form
   renderForm($vEmri, $vCmimi, NULL, $id);

   $stmt->close();
}
```

You **must** have the same number of arguments in `$stmt->bind_result()` as the number of columns your `SELECT` query is fetching.

Comment: Undeleted, but still it doesnt work if more values are added.

Comment: You must have the same number of arguments in `$stmt->bind_result($id, $vEmri, $vCmimi);` as the columns you are fetching with your `SELECT` query. if `SELECT *` is going to be used, you have to add all the columns found in your `veturat` table as arguments in `$stmt->bind_result()`.

Comment: And just don't delete the whole question after you're done. Just accept the answer if its helpful.

Comment: `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, vEmri, vCmimi,vNgjyra,vLenda,vTransmisioni,vKilometra,vProdhimi,vVellimi, vEmri FROM veturat WHERE id=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id, $vEmri, $vCmimi, $vNgjyra, $vLenda, $vTransmisioni, $vKilometra, $vProdhimi, $vVellimi);`

I added all of them in both, but it doesn't work. 
Still gives the same error.

Comment: It still shows the same error. 
Won't delete it sorry.

Comment: OK, lets just define all the columns **explicitly**. 9 columns fetched, 9 variables passed as arguments. Updated.

Comment: @IndigoMass Your `bind_result` has 9 values but your query 10.

Comment: He fetches the `vEmri ` column twice. @IndigoMass just copy and paste my code from above and everything's gonna be OK.

Comment: Copy pasted your code, now it throws : error in your SQL syntax..near '��​llimi FROM veturat WHERE id=?' at line 1 in /demo/records.php on line 148

So for some reason I had to rewrite "vVellimi" bc it wasn't "correct", but now it is all good. Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, re-paste please. Some characters seemed to be in unicode encoding causing the error in your query when you've pasted them.